# Where can I find a movable toolbar demo?

Tags: delphi, toolbar

At the top of the Delphi IDE is a toolbar with buttons grouped together on little movable trays.  I'm trying to implement something like that, but not having much success.  I've found TToolbar, but I can't figure out how to set up the movable trays.  Does anyone know where I could find a simple demo app that shows how it's done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the webbrows.dpr located in the cool stuff demo directory (and included in all installs of Delphi since around Delphi 6 or so) contains just the demo you are looking for.  This gives you the effect your looking for using only CodeGear supplied components.  You add multiple bands and set the fixed size to false for the bands you want to allow to be movable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [Toolbar2000](http://www.jrsoftware.org/tb2k.php#features) Component from Jordan Russell or the TBX package wich is an extension for Toolbar2000 components.

Toolbar2000 is a set of components for CodeGear Delphi and C++Builder designed to mimic the Office 2000 look and behavior. It includes draggable and **dockable toolbars** and menus.

[alt text http://www.indasoftware.com/_files/img/fordev/office2003/small_classic.png](http://www.indasoftware.com/_files/img/fordev/office2003/small_classic.png)

you can see these links.

- [Office2003 Theme for TBX](http://www.indasoftware.com/fordev/office2003/)
- [Mac OSX Theme for TBX](http://www.codexp.com/tbxthemes/)
- [TBX themes](http://rmklever.com/?cat=7)

Bye.

Comment: I looked at it.  Unfortunately, it's GPL-licensed, which isn't compatible with a bunch of other code I'm using, such as the JVCL, which is MPL-licensed.

Comment: Toolbar2000 is not free for commercial usage

Comment: I'm not even trying to use this for commercial usage. This is for an open-source project. I'm just a little mystified that the author chose for his open-source licensing option a license that's incompatible with almost all the rest of the Delphi open-source code out there. (How many other Delphi GPL libraries do you know of?)

Comment: ToolBar2000 is GPL since that is the only component license that requires that your application is also open source.  I am sure he licensed it that way so you would be motivated to register.  Although it closes out all other types of open source projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your toolbars in a standard VCL TCoolBar or TControlBar. AFAIR this can get a bit messy sometimes. For an example, have a look at the CoolStuff demo, as [skamradt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556392/where-can-i-find-a-movable-toolbar-demo/1556812#1556812) suggested.

Comment: All right.  The problem, though, isn't choosing what control to use so much as figuring out how to set it up.  You know where I could find some examples?